# Проблемы с django openserver?

Tags: python, django, openserver

В общем, установил django На Openserver.
Установка(скопировала кажись) все в питон, но и так же оставила в папке, где и был сам django(скачал с офф. архив и разархивировал).
В общем, установил 2 домена для каждой папки, при заходе на домен - выводится просто структура папки(По идеи, должна начальная страница зпускаться, понимаю, что нужно указать что-то типа Rewrite On, но ничего не нашел для django)? 
И еще проблема с самим отображением файлов .py(mod_wsgi установлен, без фрейма все работает)
Ошибка:
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
Или же:
Error message: 
End of script output before headers: test.py
(Если создаю чистый файл и прописываю путь к Perl)

Comment: Для чего используется openserver опишете подбробнее. Запуск на windows из под apache2 возможен, но похоже вам инструкция будет лишней, т.к. реальной необходимости не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

**Openserver для Django не нужен, как и для нового php не обязателен.**

У django свой встроенный веб сервер для разработки. Запускается.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

По умолчанию будет работать на порту 8000, http://localhost:8000

Второй сайт запускаем на другом порту

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

если запустим так, то будет доступен и из локальной сети

http://localhost:8001/ - локальный
http://192.168.1.141/ - внутрисетевой.

Запуск uwsgi приложения как cgi perl не возможен.